# How to access a router properties through bash script?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, bash-scripting

I want to change name and IP address of router by bash script not by accessing router admin page through webUI.

Comment: What router model do you have?

Comment: NETGEAR WGR614(v9)

Answer (score 2):

Typically, consumer routers are not designed for easy command line control.

*Many* linux based routers *may* have support for ssh (which is awesome) or telnet (which is insecure) and may use *standard* commands under the hood - possibly with busybox.

However, what's under the hood is usually a morass of undocumented, unsupported software, not really designed to be accessed by mere mortals. Its *pretty* risky, but its there.

In the case of netgear - the openwrt wiki suggests [the existance of a telnet daemon](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/netgear/telnet.console) - summonable by the <strike>proper incantations</strike> a specific magic packet, sent with a tool called telnetenabled.

I can't seem find anything *useful* there outside changing the username and password, though I suppose it may store hostnames and IP addresses too.

How you would script the whole "telnet -> change values -> reset" process would depend on what's there I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Use CURL to emulate a web client programatically.  I believe you would have to do it through a web interface - at least until the point you have enabled telnet - but that will be more effort then just using Curl.